# Will a reaction happen slower if it has a higher enthalpy change than its counterparts?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, enthalpy

[image]

Suppose both reactions are conducted in identical conditions and they have the same activation energy, and B has 0 enthalpy. Which one will happen faster? My experiment said reaction A happen slower than B but I have no idea why. Is it because of the enthalpy change difference, or other factors?
Thank you!

Comment: Going from left to right both reactions could have the same rate constant as the barrier to overcome is the same and so number of molecules with enough energy to cross is the same, assuming everything else is the same.  So $\Delta H$ does not come into it. Going from right to left,  the barrier is less in A than B so rate constant bigger, everything else being the same.

Comment: Unless reactions are far from equilibrium, there must be subtracted backward reaction rates from forward reaction rates, providing net reaction rates. This gives the hint the net reaction rate of A is smaller.

Comment: What exactly was your experiment? Did you monitor the reactant concentration, the product concentration, or something different. Was it a real or a simulated experiment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Diagram A, one puts in X amount of energy to get "over the hump", and, as the reaction completes, gets out somewhat **less** than X. That means one has to continually feed in energy to keep the reaction going... some energy is consumed.

In Diagram B, it appears that as much energy comes out of the reaction as was put into it, implying that energy can be recovered for the reaction to continue.

If *more* energy is released than added, then the reaction is not just *self sustaining*, but can proceed *very* rapidly, as more and more heat accumulates. An example would be thermite: $\ce{Fe2O3 + 2Al->Al2O3 + Fe}$.

This is not *exactly* as simple as stated, though. For example, in Diagram B, perhaps the energy source is heat, but the reaction emits *light* (chemiluminescence), allowed to escape, so more heat must be added -- some heat is being lost as light.